# Is Varnish+Redis+Memcached+Nginx a good idea?

Tags: magento2, varnish

We've just launched [www.artlounge.in](http://www.artlounge.in) on a Digital Ocean droplet using Cloudways,

As part of the cloudways offering you can have all the below activated at the same time

- Varnish
- Memcached
- Redis
- Nginx

Is it a good idea to ask my agency to have them all turned on?
Currently Varnish isn't enabled while the others are enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Magento to perform well, you'll need Redis and Varnish.

- Redis is a distributed key-value store that is used to cache information coming from the database
- Varnish is a reverse caching proxy that is used to cache entire pages

I wouldn't use Memcached, because it performs the same role as Redis. I'd consider Memcached the predecessor of Redis and Redis has more features.

As far as Nginx is concerned, using activating it depends on the use case. I would use Nginx as a webserver and maybe even as a TLS proxy. But I wouldn't use Nginx as a page cache.

After activating Redis & Varnish, please configure your Magento to properly connect with both.

For Redis, the connection string needs to be added to a config file so that Magento can store objects in Redis.

For Varnish, you need to put Varnish in front of your webserver, which will require a webserver reconfiguration. You'll also have to configure Magento and make Magento aware of Varnish to ensure Magento cache invalidations also cause specific invalidations in the Varnish cache.

For Varnish setup and Magento VCL configuration, please have a look at https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-magento/